# Access to particular URL for file reading in JS

Tags: javascript, file

I am trying to read a file in Java script. I am using XAMPP server, all the files are in the htdocs folder. But when I try to read a file from other directory its not working.

Error:

```
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied
request.send(null);
```

JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <textarea id="box" rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>


<script>

//get the contents of the text file START   
//Make sure in the JsonData.txt file, after each line there should not be any space ie when you click RIGHT arrow at the end of each line the cursor should go to next line beginning.


            function FileHelper()
            {}
            {
                FileHelper.readStringFromFileAtPath = function(pathOfFileToReadFrom)
                {
                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    request.open("GET", pathOfFileToReadFrom, false);
                    request.send(null);
                    var returnValue = request.responseText;

                    return returnValue;
                }
            }

            var pathOfFileToRead = "file://d:/sampleData.txt";

            var contentsOfFileAsString = FileHelper.readStringFromFileAtPath
            (
                pathOfFileToRead
            );

            var contents_value = contentsOfFileAsString;
            alert(contents_value);
            document.getElementById("box").value = contents_value;

            //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = contents_value;       

            //get the contents of the text file STOP
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the JS 'pathOfFileToRead=filepath' if I keep the file in the same htdocs directory its working fine, but not working if I give local directory path like I have given in the above JS.

Answer (score 2):

You're using javascript running in the browser. You can't use the file:// protocol to read your file, and you can't use drive letters.

You can still do what you want to do though. You need to reference your file with an url and call it with http://. (You know the difference ?! An url has a domain name or ip address pointing to a web root, then perhaps a port number, then forward slashes separating each folder below the web root. A windows path has a drive letter, then backslashes separating each folder.)

There are tons of litte things to improve in your script. I would start with removing the pair of empty braces on line 2. Then, I don't think anyone uses xmlhttp in synchronous mode. You should really be using asynch with callbacks, and checking for success (200) before doing your business.